# Is Benacerraf's argument circular?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-mathematics

I'm reading Benacerraf's *What numbers could not be*, where he provides the following argument against platonistic account of numbers.

1. The only criteria we can ask for in searching the correct account of numbers is that (a) it should include definitions of numbers and operations by which the laws of arithmetics can be derived, and (b) it should explain the application of numbers, notably counting.
2. There are many set theoretic accounts of numbers that satisfy (a) and (b), but have conflicting nature. For example, defining 0 = ∅, 1 = {∅}, 2 = {∅, {∅}}, ... yields 0 ∈ 2, which is not true with 0 = ∅, 1 = {∅}, 2 = {{∅}}, ....
3. As there is no reason to favour one account over another, the correct set theoretic account of numbers does not exist. Thus, numbers are not sets.
4. Indeed, numbers cannot be platonistic, since any account of numbers in terms of mathematical objects would encounter the same problem.

However, I find this argument fallacious. In physics, the only criterion we can ask for in searching the correct theory is that it should be empirically adequate. However, we have several *metaphysically* conflicting interpretations of quantum theory with equivalent *empirical* consequences. Yet this does not compel us to concede that no correct interpretation of quantum theory exists.

Likewise, a platonist about numbers can reasonably hold that although there are several *arithmetically* equivalent reduction of numbers, there is only one *metaphysically* correct reduction. So it seems that Benacerraf's argument against platonism can be rejected by holding platonism, thus circular. Have I misunderstood his argument?

Comment: QM and arithmetic are very dissimilar. QM is a black box, we have not determined the 'right' description of what's inside yet, but perhaps we might. Arithmetic is not a black box, it is a conception *we use*. We know *exactly* what's inside, "*conditions which were both necessary and sufficient for any correct account*", as he puts it. Yet, with sets "*we have two... each of which satisfies what appear to be necessary and sufficient conditions*". Either one of them has platonically 'right' 3, but its 'distinction' has nothing to do with the 3 we use, or 3 can't be a set. That's the dilemma.

Comment: What we do not yet know about physics may well tell us which interpretation of QM is really the case, if any. On the other hand, *nothing* we do not yet know about arithmetic (some deep theorems or whatnot) can tell us which set 3 'really' is. Thus, set-theoretic platonism about numbers is either irrelevant to *our* arithmetic, or false.

Comment: @Conifold Thanks for the comments, but I don't think QM and arithmetics are "very" dissimilar here. Imagine a case where scientists made all the possible empirical observations about QM, yet there are still different interpretations of QM standing. Such case seems identical to the current coexistence of several set theoretic interpretations of arithmetic. Then wouldn't your conclusion imply that realism about quantum theory is either irrelevant to *our* (empirical) quantum theory, or false?

Comment: @Dimen In physics, we deal only with approximate models, so it is very possible that 2 approximations with differing metaphysical implications both produce reasonably accurate models. However in the case of mathematical logic, numbers and sets are very well defined, not as approximations, but as objects obeying an exhaustive collection of axioms and deduction rules. When dealing with approximations, there is the possibility of finding yet another approximation that will work better. But that is not the case for numbers and sets.

Comment: @Dimen By the consistency of logical deduction, if you encounter one contradiction, you are "done". There is no working around that contradiction through another deductive path.

Comment: One counter to Benacerraf's argument could be though that numbers are not a specific set of sets, but the class of all set of sets which have the same cardinal. The metaphysical status of "class" in that sense may be difficult though.

Comment: I don't see that the argument is circular, but it seems to assume that for numbers to exist as abstract objects, they have to be reducible to something else. Also, the claim that any theory would have the same problems he points out for sets has already been shown to be false by neo-Fregeans.

Comment: Scientists cannot make all possible empirical observations about QM even in principle, there are infinitely many of them, and even if they could they couldn't know they did without God-like powers. But they can know everything that determines arithmetic, and know that they know it, because it is of our own making. If they did exhaust the metaphysics of QM and still had multiple interpretations then *those* would indeed be either irrelevant or false. But this imagined situation will have little to do with the one we are in. Only God can know reality the way we know arithmetic, as its creators.

Comment: I agree that IMO there is no circularity there... The issue is that B's argument shows that the Platonistic view about number as abstract objects cannot be grounded into the identification of numbers with sets, due to the fact that there are "metaphysically" different construction of numbers that are set-theoretically equivalent.